# MPDF PDF formatting

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am trying to convert a complete webpage as-is to PDF as part of my final year university project, and have found MPDF extremely useful for this task, however I'm struggling a little with the presentation of the actual output.

The page itself looks like below:
[image: Original webpage]

and I would like it to be presented exactly as it is above when converted to PDF, however converting seems to remove all styles from the document, presenting it like so:
[image: Converted webpage]

The code I have used to convert the page is below:

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
    include("checklog.php"); 
    require_once("watchlist-controller.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/fav.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <title>Screening - Your ticket to your movies - <?php echo $watchlist_name; ?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="Screening is a brand new take on the traditional movie database, fusing social networking and multimedia to provide a clear, concise experience allowing you to share your favourite movies, and discover new classics.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Movies, Films, Screening, Discover, Watch, Share, experience, database, movie database, film database, share film, share films, discover film, discover films, share movie, share movies, discover movie, discover movies">

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/custom-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.less" />
        <script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Start Google Analytics -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
        </script>
        <!-- End Google Analytics -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container"><?php 
            require_once ("header.php");?>
            <div id="main" class="well main-content">
                <p class="page-title"><?php echo $watchlist_name; ?></p>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <section class="span12 watchlist-holder film-list"><?php
                        if (count($films) == 0) {?>
                            <div class="alert alert-info">This Watchlist is empty! Why not visit a movie page to add something to it?</div><?php
                        } else {?>
                            <ul class="unstyled"><?php
                                foreach($films as $key => $film_item) {
                                    include("watchlist-film-controller.php");?>
                                    <li class="well list-item clearfix">
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <a href="movie.php?id=<?php echo $rt_id; ?>" class="span1 pull-left" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $poster_thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?> poster" title="<?php echo $title; ?> poster" /></a>

                                            <div class="span11 movie-info">
                                                <p class="search-title"><a href="movie.php?id=<?php echo $film_item['film_id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?> (<?php echo $year; ?>)"><?php echo $title; ?></a> <small>(<?php echo $year; ?>)</small></p><?php

                                                if ($critics_consensus == "") {?>
                                                    <p class="watchlist-synopsis">No overview available</p><?php
                                                } else {?>
                                                    <p class="watchlist-synopsis"><?php echo $critics_consensus; ?></p><?php
                                                }?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li><?php
                                }?>
                            </ul><?php
                        }?>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div><?php
            include 'footer.html'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html><?php
$HTMLoutput = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
//Convert HTML 2 PDF by using MPDF PHP library
include ("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($HTMLoutput);
$mpdf->Output();?>
```

I'm not the most experienced of PHP coders, and I'm still learning much as I go along, so any pointers would be appreciated. I'm not sure if the way I've attempted to convert using MPDF is the best way to approach the problem, either, which may be an issue.

Comment: not all PDF creators support full CSS elements such as background colours/images etc.  Take a look at replacing mpdf with DOMPDF http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ it works a little differently and resolves alot of the issues most other pdf creators have with converting html to pdf.  Its not got the advantages of the other pdf creators for other bits pieces but for html to pdf its pretty damn good and very fast.